# How to mark first character?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to mask email, so if I have this email:

```
harrypotter@gmail.com
```

after masking it I want to show it like this:

```
h**********@g****.c**
```

Basically always show ONLY the first character in the beginning, the first character after @ symbol, and first character after .com (Example: only show letter c)

This is my code:

```js
let myEmail = "harrypotter@gmail.com".replace(/^(.).+?(?=@)/, '$1***').replace(/(@.).+?(?=\.\w+$)/, '$1***')
console.log(myEmail);
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing or if this could be simplified in a better way? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You'll have to think about email addresses with subdomains like `@my.constructed.example.com`. How do you want to deal with those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all word characters except the first one and prefixed with a non word character:

```js
let myEmail = "harrypotter2@gmail.com".replace(/(?<!(\W|^))\w/g, '*');
console.log(myEmail);
```

But when the name part contains dots and special characters like often used `+` we end up with a more complex regex like:

`(?<!(^|@))[^@](?!\w+$)` - here we replace all characters that aren't `@` except the first one and after `@` and before the top level domain

`(?<=\w)\w(?=\w+$)` - here we replace the characters in the top level domain except the first one

```js
let myEmail = "harry.potter+job@gmail.com".replace(/(?<!(^|@))[^@](?!\w+$)|(?<=\w)\w(?=\w+$)/g, '*');
console.log(myEmail);
```

Also we have an option manually split and mask:

```js
let myEmail = 'harry.potter+job@gmail.com';
const [name, domain] = myEmail.split('@');

const hide = str => str[0] + '*'.repeat(str.length - 1);

myEmail = hide(name) + '@' + domain.split('.').map(hide).join('.');

console.log(myEmail);
```

Which is actually faster than the regex:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1000000">

const myEmail = 'harry.potter+job@gmail.com';

// @benchmark regex

myEmail.replace(/(?<!(^|@))[^@](?!\w+$)|(?<=\w)\w(?=\w+$)/g, '*');

// @benchmark string splitting and padding
const [name, domain] = myEmail.split('@');
const hide = str => str[0] + '*'.repeat(str.length - 1);
hide(name) + '@' + domain.split('.').map(hide).join('.');

</script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```